# Share Windows Phone 8.1 application developed with Visual Studio to friends

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I want to know how is possible to share a Windows Phone 8.1 applications, developed in Visual Studio, to friends, without publish it on the Store. Is it possible like Android with .apk? What is the procedure to export it from Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create App packages:

1. Right click on your solution
2. Select "Store"
3. Select "Create App Packages"
4. "Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Phone store?" Select "No"

From that on it is straightforward. You can than install this package on an unlocked Windows Phone. Another approach is to register on https://dev.windows.com/en-us, and upload your app as a beta version, than add your friends as beta testers, so they can donwload it from the store  (it will be hidden from the store, only testers can download it).

Comment: Thank, so with beta test, I can share the application to only the friend I choice, isn't it ? So to let them able to install the application, I need their Windows Phone Store account, isn't it ?

Comment: Right, you need their microsoft account which is used on their phones

Comment: If I follow this instructions my options is greyed out. What am I missing